# NVMe drives and compatibility

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, nvme

I am trying to understand the issues with the new NVMe interface and older motherboards.

I have a [Gigabyte GA-Z87X-OC](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4514) and I simply cannot workout whether I should buy NVMe or AHCI.

**In short:**

If I buy an NVMe drive for a motherboard that doesn't support NVMe natively, which of these scenarios is the correct one:

1 - I cannot boot into my NVMe drive, but I can take full NVME advantage as a secondary drive

2 - I cannot boot into my NVMe drive, but I can use it as a secondary drive with some limitations

3 - I cannot use my NVMe drive at all

Comment: AHCI isn't really a type of drive.  NVMe is limited to SSD which are connected over PCI-E where as AHCI is limited to SATA.  So the question is does your motherboard support M.2 drives which is likely the only way it would support NVMe

Comment: @Ramhound This is (partially) incorrect. There are many PCIe SSDs that use AHCI and this is what you will need for even many of the latest Skylake machines, although NVMe is specifically designed for SSDs and PCIe and will become more dominant.

Comment: Read what I said?  Basically said that.

Comment: @Ramhound  "..where as AHCI is limited to SATA."  That's wrong and also implies that all PCIe SSDs use NVMe, which is also incorrect.

Comment: @paradroid is right! Also, there are some NVMe drives that are connected through SATA Express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have found exactly what I am looking for in this article:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2899351/everything-you-need-to-know-about-nvme.html

Quoted from the article:

> One of the best things about NVM Express is that you don’t have to worry about drivers showing up. Linux has had NVMe support since kernel 3.1; Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 both include a native driver, and there’s a FreeBSD driver in the works. When Apple decides to support NVMe, the latter should make it easy to port.
>
> However, BIOS support is largely lacking. **Without an NVMe-aware BIOS, you can’t boot from an NVMe drive, though anyone with a x4 PCIe slot or M.2 connector can benefit from employing an NVMe drive as secondary storage**.

Comment: According to this guide the Asus Z87-Expert with the latest UEFI should be able to boot from NVMe. Shouldn't the F8 version of your motherboard support it too? http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/nvme_boot_guide_332098001us.pdf

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, it looks very possible! I will soon buy a disk and find out